# Why the need to define $L^2 (\partial \Omega)$, when $\Omega$ is Lipschitz domain?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Why is there a need to define $L^2 (\partial \Omega)$ with $\Omega$ being a Lipschitz, open and connected set, when we already know how to define $L^2(\Omega)$?

$L^2(\Omega)=\{u: \int_{\Omega} u^2<\infty \}$ with $u:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Couldn't we just do $L^2(\partial \Omega)=\{u: \int_{\partial \Omega} u^2<\infty \}$ with $u:\partial 
 \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I ask this question, since I'm reading a book on PDEs and, before talking about Traces of generalized functions, the author takes a moment to define $L^2(\partial \Omega)$.

Edit to reflect some comments.

If we use a different measure $\mu$ for $\partial \Omega$, then wouldn't the following still be valid?
$$L^2(\partial \Omega)=\{u: \int_{\partial \Omega} u^2(x) d\mu<\infty \}$$ with $u:\partial 
 \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Comment: The measure you use on $\partial \Omega$ is different

Comment: The measure you use on the boundary is different, and also the values of an $L^2$ function on the boundary are not strictly well-defined on a null set, which is why you need the notion of trace in the first place.

Comment: @LukasRollier In what way is that measure different?

Comment: Well, your integral doesn't always come out to be $0$, while using the Lebesgue measure on $\partial \Omega$ does come out to be $0$.

Comment: @Ian Why is it different? Because $\partial \Omega$ on the same measure used for $\Omega$ would be zero? But if I use a different measure, then we will have the functions well defined. So, let us use a different measure. In my original question, let's use a different measure for $\partial \Omega$. Couldn't we just still used what's written there?

Comment: The interest of such a notion is to make a link between a function being $L^2$ on an open set and its value, on some sense, over the boundary.

Comment: @LukasRollier So, let's use a different measure. Would that invalidate what I have written in the edit?

Comment: If you indeed use a different measure (usually what is called the 'surface measure'), then what you wrote seems to me to be correct

Comment: Once you change to the surface measure and identify $u$ on the boundary with its trace, then you're good. But a very important technicality arises: you have to be careful about the domain of the trace operator. Not every function in $L^2(\Omega)$ has a trace. Some Sobolev regularity is required.

Comment: Also changing the measure on the interior isn't going to work; the fact that $u$ is not strictly well-defined on the boundary is an inevitable thing, you're not going to get around it.

Comment: @Ian, if you consolidate your comments, and elaborate just a bit more, I'll gladly accept it as an answer, and I'll even include a +1.

Comment: @LukasRollier thanks for the comments ;) If you want, you can consolidate your comments, and elaborate just a bit more, and I'll gladly accept it as an answer (or Ian's, whichever does one best), and I'll even include a +1.

Comment: @Ian, you feel like it? I'm a bit tired.